# Python doubling backslashes when using; with open(C:\directory_name) as file_object (PyCharm IDE)

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I am using (PyCharm IDE):

```
with open("C:\file_path\target_file") as path_object:
```

It always doubles the the drive backslash.

I've tried input the path using a raw string, same result;

```
file_path = r"C:\file_path\target_file"
```

and I've tried pathlib/Path, same result;

```
from pathlib import Path

file_path = Path("C:\file_path\target_file")
```

The second backslash comes out as intended but the drive backslash always doubles, no matter what. When printing the file path, console shows the path correctly.

Also I've tried escaping the backslashes (\), and it doesn't work. When searching for the path it prints it as double.

Comment: Are you able to access the `target_File` by any of these codes? if yes! Escaping the backslashes might not be of concern

Comment: Ah no, not when starting a path from a drive. It works fine when I give a path that's nested in the project file.

Comment: Also you are missing a double quote in `with open("C:\file_path\target_file) as path_object:`

Comment: "When printing the file path, console shows the path correctly","when searching for the path it prints it as double" aren't these two statements contradicting each other?

Comment: print() with the file path does fine like I said, but open() returns a FileNotFoundError with the path having a double backslash on the drive.

Comment: The `repr` version of a string will show a backslash as ```\\```. It does not indicate a problem. Post a [mcve] that actually includes the problem you are seeing, and explain why it is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between the string's contents and what the REPL displays. For example:

```
>>> '''I am a multiline
... string
... '''
'I am a multiline\nstring\n'
>>> print('I am a multiline\nstring\n')
I am a multiline
string

>>>
```

The two represent the exact same string, even though one contains literal newlines and the other contains newline literals (`\n`). This is because the REPL calls `repr(your_string)` before printing it out so that the string can fit into one line.

In your case, `\f` and `\t` are actually mistakes:

```
>>> print("C:\file_path\target_file")
C:
  ile_path  arget_file
```

This is because `\t` represents a tab and `\f` represents a form feed, just like `\n` represents a newline. The double backslash is actually correct since you want `\` to literally mean a backslash, not the start of an escape sequence:

```
>>> print("C:\\file_path\\target_file")
C:\file_path\target_file
```

Using a raw string has the same effect:

```
>>> print(r"C:\file_path\target_file")
C:\file_path\target_file
```